# CRM executionContext to workflow entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

From a CRM custom workflow, I need to get the actual 'Workflow' entity from the executionContext.  I'm trying to retrieve the WorkflowId and Workflow name that are stored under the 'Processes' UI

Does anybody have a sample query they are willing to share?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are referring the record that triggered the workflow(i.e. if you are set it to trigger on create of account you would want the account record that triggered the workflow)?

There are several options (including the use of input parameters). Here I will use the WorkflowContext to get the Primary Entity Id.

```
public String GetRecordIdFromRecordThatTriggeredWorkflow(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        String someString = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Set up the workflow context 
            IWorkflowContext workFlowContext = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

            someString = workFlowContext.PrimaryEntityId.ToString();
            return someString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Error occured in GetFeeWaiverId Method:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps!

**Edit:** 
Here is a link that has the query you are looking for. [Get Current WorkflowId](http://extremecrm.net/2013/04/25/executing-a-dynamics-crn-workflow-from-a-plugin/)

Comment: No I want to get to the Workflow entity, not the entity that triggered the workflow.

Comment: Thanks.  I've already got it working querying by the workflow name but I don't want to hardcode the workflow name in the code.  This link looks promising but I will need to go WorkflowInstanceID -> asyncoperation (System Jobs) -> Workflow http://markuserlandsson.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/converting-workflow-counter-to-crm-2013/